Infinite gas in REMIX-IDE - smart contracts
I am learning solidity using remix-ide.
I am having a gas limit error in the functions: fundSender() and startTransaction(address _WORKER, uint256 _AMOUNT)
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

contract TransactContract {
  address public CONTRACTOR;
  address public WORKER;
  uint256 public AMOUNT;
  bool public contractor_accepted;
  bool public worker_accepted;
  bool public transact_is_started;

  event TRANSACT_IS_STARTED(address indexed CONTRACTOR, address indexed WORKER, uint256 AMOUNT);
  event TRANSACT_ACCEPTED(address indexed stakeholder);
  event LIQUID_FUNDS(address indexed stakeholder, uint256 AMOUNT);

  constructor() {
    CONTRACTOR = address(0);
    WORKER = address(0);
    AMOUNT = 0;
    contractor_accepted = false;
    worker_accepted = false;
    transact_is_started = false;
  }

  function startTransaction(address _WORKER, uint256 _AMOUNT) external {
    require(!transact_is_started, "Contract in progress.");
    CONTRACTOR = msg.sender;
    WORKER = _WORKER;
    AMOUNT = _AMOUNT;
    transact_is_started = true;

    emit TRANSACT_IS_STARTED(CONTRACTOR, WORKER, AMOUNT);
  }

  function acceptTransaction() external {
    require(msg.sender == CONTRACTOR || msg.sender == WORKER, "Only stakeholders part of the contract can interact.");
    require(transact_is_started, "Transaction has not started yet.");

    if(msg.sender == WORKER) {
      require(!worker_accepted, "Worker has already fulfilled the clauses.");
      worker_accepted = true;
      contractor_accepted = true;
    } else {
      require(!contractor_accepted, "Contractor has accepted the clauses.");
      contractor_accepted = true;
      worker_accepted = true;
    }

    emit TRANSACT_ACCEPTED(msg.sender);
  }

  function fundSender() external payable {
    require(worker_accepted && contractor_accepted, "Both parties must have accepted the contract terms."); 
    require(msg.value == AMOUNT, "The contract does not have sufficient funds to send.");

    (bool success, ) = payable(WORKER).call{value: msg.value}("");
    require(success, "Funds liquidation successful.");

    emit LIQUID_FUNDS(WORKER, msg.value);
  }
}

I managed to get everything working except the part where the funds are sent to the WORKER. Does anyone know why? or could you provide me with a guide on where to learn more about solidity in remix-ide?
